# Text File Integer import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I just can't seem to solve this. I know others use this exact code and it works for them; why would I get an error and others not? I use Python 3.6.3

```
with open('Numbers.txt') as f:
    alist = [int(num) for num in f]

print(alist[0])
print(alist[99999])
print(alist())
```

Output:

```
54044
91901
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(alist())
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Also did below with the same error:

```
with open('Numbers.txt') as f:
    numbers = f.readlines()

numbers = [int(x.strip()) for x in numbers]

print(numbers[0])
print(len(numbers()))
```

Comment: _"I know others use this exact code and it works for them"_. Are you 100% sure about that? Do you have a link?

Comment: It is clear, lists are not callable, so you can not use ()

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-divide-conquer/discussions/all/threads/t8OC-gWcEee36g5uvZCkbA

Comment: I'm expecting to see a list of 100000 integers. I want to use it in a Sort algorithm. The algorithm works with test array inputs, but not with this list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the list on `line 8`, see `alist()`. Lists aren't callable. If you want the full list, just do `alist`.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid.  You used parentheses instead of brackets.

```
alist()
```

Is not a valid use; the parentheses signal to the parser that you want to use `alist` as a function.  What do you *want* this to do?

The second one has the same problem.  For that, I think you just want the name without parentheses:

```
print (len(numbers))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm embarrassed, should have picked that up.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `()` indicates that you want to call or execute something, a function for example. You were trying to call numbers by `numbers()` in the last line, which is a list, not a function. Change it to `numbers` to get the length of the list `numbers`.

```
with open('Numbers.txt') as f:
    numbers = f.readlines()

numbers = [int(x.strip()) for x in numbers]

print(numbers[0])
print(len(numbers))
```

Comment: Please explain what/how your contribution solves the OPs question.